# UITableVC No section header content shown

Tags: swift, tableview, sectionheader

converting my code to swift ONLY so no use of storyboards. After rewriting the code (no storyboard usage) the header information is NOT shown !!

If I change the viewForHeaderInSection return value from:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerId") as! ListsVCHeader
    cell.fillHeader(header: listTitles[section])

    return cell.contentView
}
```

to:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerId") as! ListsVCHeader
    cell.fillHeader(header: listTitles[section])

    return cell  // ==> removed .contectView
}
```

the header content is shown BUT the section header moves left performing a swipe gesture that I use to initiate a row delete. Any suggestions? Find the relevant code below.

```
class ListsVC: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(ListsVCHeader.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "headerId")
        // register other Cells
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return listTitles.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)
    -> String? {
        return listTitles[section]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerId") as! ListsVCHeader
        cell.fillHeader(header: listTitles[section])
        return cell.contentView
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return HeaderSectionHeight
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        switch editingStyle {
        case .delete:
            // mycode
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

the Section Header cell

```
class ListsVCHeader: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // add subviews and constraints
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func fillHeader (header: String) {
        name.text = header
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have both titleForHeaderInSection & viewForHeaderInSection methods implemented?

Comment: Well spotted. If I only use: titleForHeaderInSection it works. But I have another issue. The system is using the default font size of the label and I need the label not vertical centered but 30pt from the top. To implement this I used viewForHeaderInSection. Any suggestion to change the header section font and have custom constraints for the header section text using titleForHeaderInSection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `register` in `viewDidLoad` to:

```
tableView.register(ListsVCHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "headerId")
```

Your class `ListsVCHeader` should be changed to:

```
class ListsVCHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView
```

and last change the following code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerId") as! ListsVCHeader
```

to

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "headerId) as! ListsVCHeader
```

Comment: No problem! Could you please up vote and mark the answer as correct so others with the same problem know too? :)